# Htaccess Pass IP to Php

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I am currently trying to secure my server with htaccess to allow only local access of certain directories. One of the issues I am having is  debugging certain calls. Is it possible to pass the IP of the request to PHP from htaccess.

For example I have the following to allow local only

```
ErrorDocument 403 http://172.26.0.6/who.php?ip=%{REMOTE_ADDR}
order deny,allow
deny from all
allow from 127.0.0.1
allow from localhost
```

Ideally I would like to redirect all those that do not match the criteria to a php file so that I can log the request and the ip's, some of these may be false positives so it will help me identify the ip's that are being blocked and should not be. The main goal is to pass from htaccess to php.

Answer (score 1):

The `%{REMOTE_ADDR}` variable is actually a server variable, and already available in PHP. The [global `$_SERVER`](https://devdocs.io/php/reserved.variables.server) references all the server side variables:

> ### `REMOTE_ADDR`
>
> The IP address from which the user is viewing the current page.

So, in your PHP script:

```
<?php
    echo $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
?>
```

Comment: Many thanks for the response, although this certainly gets the ip, how would I go about passing variables ie the ip from htaccess to php, this is more for my knowledge than actual implementation of the exact scenario.